# jquery easyui combobox data with sub-array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

Here is my sample code:

```
      <th data-options="field:'category',width:100,
                editor:{
                type:'combobox',
                options:{
                    valueField:'id',
                    textField:'categoryName',
                    method:'get',
                    url:'/categories/list',
                    required:true
                }}">Category</th>

My response data from url is:
{"rows":

[{"id":"4028b8814c4470d4014c4474ec4d0001","categoryName":"ASDFASDF","categoryDescription":"ASDFASDFASDF","status":"active","datetime":"2015-03-23T10:27:35.629+08:00"},
{"id":"4028b8814c41d8bd014c41dfd8dc0004","categoryName":"NO CATEGORY","categoryDescription":"NO CATEGORY","status":"active","datetime":"2015-03-23T10:27:35.629+08:00"},{"id":"4028b8814c4470d4014c447508e50002","categoryName":"ASDFASDF2","categoryDescription":"ASDFASDFASDF","status":"active","datetime":"2015-03-23T10:27:42.949+08:00"},

{"id":"4028b8814c4470d4014c447c2c4d0003","categoryName":"ASDFASDF","categoryDescription":"ASDFASDF","status":"active","datetime":"2015-03-23T10:35:30.765+08:00"},

{"id":"4028b8814c4470d4014c44a00d6e0004","categoryName":"TEST1","categoryDescription":"ADFASDFAFD","status":"active","datetime":"2015-03-23T11:14:42.154+08:00"}]

,"total":5,"item":""}
```

As you can see, my data needed for the list is inside 'rows' array.
Is there an option on jquery easyui combobox to just get the data inside 'rows'?

Thanks,
ModLoaded

Answer (score 0):

Use an Ajax call to load JS variable and Use that JS variable to load the combobox.

```
var comboData=null;

$.ajax({url: '/categories/list',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (output, status, xhr) {   
               comboData=output.rows;
          }
});
```

In your combobox, use as follows,

```
<th data-options="field:'category',width:100,
                    editor:{
                    type:'combobox',
                    options:{
                        valueField:'id',
                        textField:'categoryName',
                        method:'get',
                        data:comboData,
                        required:true
                    }}">Category</th>
```